# ng2-daterangepicker - endDate is always resetting while selecting startDate in custom date range option

Tags: angular, angular5

I am  using https://github.com/evansmwendwa/ng2-daterangepicker in my angular 5 project. The scenario is below:

1. I am selecting the startDate and endDate from custom date range and applying the changes, it's working fine(for the very first time).
2. When i am repeating the same step from second time on wards i found that whenever, i am selecting the startDate, it's resetting the endDate always, even though i have endDate value.

### My question :

1. Is there a way, so that, if i will select the startDate the endDate should not be reset
   automatically, or if there is a value for endDate it should not reset itSelf?
2. Is there a way to detect the startDate or endDate selection changes?

I am using ng2-daterangepicker version 2.0.12. Thanks in advance.